SQL command to delete bulk WP post specific
I have an author named News Agencies and it has 50000 WordPress post from 5 months, I need to delete news agencies post from this specific author of 3 months only. Is there any SQLI command to do this task?
Specific author >> from December to march

Deleting posts directly in the DB is not going to clear up all their comments, post metadata, etc. I'd recommend using wp_delete_post() to do this instead.

// Gets the post IDs.
$author_id = get_user_by( 'login', 'newsagencies' ); // Use the user's login here.
$posts = new WP_Query( 
  array( 
    'author' => $author_id,
    'date_query' => array(
      'after' => '2023-12-01',
      'before' => '2024-03-31', 
    ),
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // Get *all* the posts.
  ),
);

$force_delete = true; // Set this to 'false' if you only want to trash
                      // the posts, not actually delete them permanently.

if ( ! empty( $posts->posts ) ) {
  foreach ( $posts->posts as $post_id ) {
    wp_delete_post( $post_id, $force_delete );
  }
}

Notes

With 50,000 posts, this might take a while.
This code is meant as a starting point only; it's not production-ready, and should be tested on a test site first.

References

WP_Query class
get_user_by()
wp_delete_post()

